# Maximum element. Algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, linked-list, stack

I am trying to solve Maximum element task from hackerrank. Task[link](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/maximum-element)
Idea is to implement Stack through linked list with one extra field in node which is max. It works pretty well sometimes but on bigger examples i my nodes get wrong max element. What did i do wrong ?

```
public class Stack
{
public class Node
{
    long data;
    long max;
    Node next;
}

Node head = null;

public void push(long data)
{
    if(head == null)
    {
        head = new Node();
        head.next = null;
        head.data = data;
        head.max = data;
        return;
    }

    Node current = head;

    while(current.next != null)
        current = current.next;

    Node temp = new Node();
    temp.next = null;
    temp.data = data;
    if(current.data > temp.data)
    {
        temp.max = current.data;
    }else
    {
        temp.max = data;
    }

    current.next = temp;
}

public void pop()
{
    if(head == null)
        return;

    if(head.next == null)
    {
        head = null;
        return;
    }

    Node current = head;

    while(current.next.next != null)
        current = current.next;

    current.next = null;
}
public long getMax()
{
    if(head == null)
        return -1;

    Node current = head;

    while(current.next != null)
        current = current.next;

    return current.max;
}
}
```

Comment: Your pop-method doesn't update the max-field.

Comment: What all have you done to attempt to solve the problem yourself?

Answer (score 1):

You are doing wrong comparison in push in the following line

```
if(current.data > temp.data) { temp.max = current.data; }else { temp.max = data; }
```

It has to be

```
if(current.max > temp.data) { temp.max = current.max; }else { temp.max = data; }
```

Here you have to check with the push value with the current maximum value and if the new one is greater then it is the greatest. Else the current maximum value retains its maximum value greed in the pushing node also

Comment: It was mistake, but there is also something else wrong with the code. Trying to figure out what is it.

Comment: Remaining everything looks fine i think.  Add some output linked list which seems wrong, that ll be easy to identify the problem